# Hibernate: How to persist Child object and not to touch/update parent in hibernate

Tags: database, spring, hibernate

I have a parent-child relationship in a class and I have defined the relationship as one to many.

I have a use case where I need to save only child objects and ideally not update Parent object on a button click?

how do I it.

Answer (score 0):

Call `session.save` on child objects.

Have a look into this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many

Here `session.save(item1);` only saves changes of child object item1.